# Best way to store text with an undetermined code page in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, unicode, character-encoding, codepages

I am currently writing an application (*App1*) which retrieves portions of text remotely from another application (let's call it *App2*).
There are several instances of *App2* around the world, and they all interpret their strings according to their local system code page. *App2* is not unicode-aware.

*App1* retrieves the text from *App2* without any hint as to the text's code page, but it is expected that at a latter point, a manual process will be undertaken to select the code page to correctly interpret the text.

Previous attempts to automatically determine the code page of the text have failed.

In the mean time, pending the manual determination, this data must be stored in a MySQL database.
**What is the best way to store this data?** Specifically, what `CHARSET` and `COLLATION` would be best employed here?

I believe that MySQL will not tolerate inserting characters into a field if they are not valid for the field's charset.

It would be ideal if I could detect the code page and convert the data to unicode before inserting into the database, but I am at a loss of how this can be done consistently and reliably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really do not know the character set, then you can only store it as binary data. That will preserve all the contents (nothing gets mangled). When it comes to trying to use it as a text, you will have to guess the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to store this data?

The only sane way is for App2 to send along the information what encoding the data is in.

Using that information, you could convert it to Unicode before inserting it into the database. That would be optimal.

All multi-byte libraries have functions to guess the encoding by looking at specific tell-tale byte values, but they are terribly unreliable, especially when the incoming data could  have *any* encoding.

Comment: Unfortunately, App2 does not send that information, and it is closed and proprietary. I have had the exact same experience with libraries guessing the codepage - no cigar.

Comment: @Mikuso what is going to be done with the text data afterwards?

Comment: Well App1 is primarily a piece of middleware. The text will go on to be republished in a Unicode-friendly data feed for other applications which rely on it. The data does not just consist of text though, but numerical data too. The numerical data must be collected for generation of statistics, and the text must naturally accompany it.

Comment: @Mikuso okay, so storing it as binary isn't enough, you need to make a proper conversion. I'm not sure whether there is a way to do this  - trying to detect the encoding programmatically, or having a human being monitor the incoming data (and switch encodings until it looks "right") are the only options that come to my mind in that case. If you can install a second app on the remote machine, you could maybe pry it out of the client's system and send it in separately. Don't know whether that's feasible

Comment: @Pekka hmm, yes I fully agree. Unfortunately, I am not able to install any additional apps alongside App2. I can, however, make the assumption that App2 will be running on a Windows machine, and I may be able to make certain assumptions based on the WAN IP address of the machine running App2. Is there a concrete list of code pages that Windows uses for different regions, and some way of intelligently mapping the IP address to a likely code page? Does that sound feasible?

Comment: @Mikuso that would be worth putting into a new question I think. Do post the link here if you start one